# Where can I find sony xperia M 's android source code for its camera app?

Tags: android, android-camera, sony

Is there any way I can browse sony xperia M's android source code? especially of camera application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limited source code that Sony have made available can be found at

https://github.com/sonyxperiadev

In common with other Android producers (including Google itself), they do not make the source code for their proprietary applications, including the camera app, available.